# having error with custom checkboxes in uitableview cells

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, checkbox

im getting the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'***

I have 2 sections and I am trying to make it so when you click the checkbox of a cell in one of the sections, it goes to the other section (ex: section 1->section 2)

here is some relevant code of mine:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if([indexPath section] == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxtry2.png"];
    } else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];
     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxtry2selected.png"];
    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlechecking:)];
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return cell;
}
-(void)handlechecking:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)t{
        CGPoint tapLocation = [t locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];

        if (tappedIndexPath.section == 0) {
            [completedArray addObject:[taskArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            [taskArray removeObject:[taskArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
        }
        else {
            [taskArray addObject:[completedArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            [completedArray removeObject:[completedArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tappedIndexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

I have two arrays: taskArray which handles objects in section 0 and completedArray which handles objects in section 1.

---EDIT---
Here is what I have now:
TableViewController.h

```
@interface ToDoTableViewController : UITableViewController <Properties2ViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, SettingsViewControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *taskArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *completedArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *holdViewsArray;
-(IBAction)addCell:(id)sender;
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
-(void)handlechecking:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)t;
```

TableViewController.m

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

    taskArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    completedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    holdViewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   }
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    NSString *detailText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [[taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeInterval]];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255 green:240.0/255 blue:241.0/255 alpha:1.0f]];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = baseColor;
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:detailText];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:12]];
    [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:16]];

    if([indexPath section] == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
    } else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];
     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlechecking:)];
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return cell;

}
-(void)handlechecking:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)t{

        CGPoint tapLocation = [t locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = nil;

        if (tappedIndexPath.section == 0) {

            NSUInteger newRowIndex = self.completedArray.count;
            [self.completedArray addObject:[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            [self.taskArray removeObject:[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:1];
        } else {

            NSUInteger newRowIndex = self.taskArray.count;
            [self.taskArray addObject:[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            [self.completedArray removeObject:[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
        }
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[tappedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSInteger num = 0;
    if (section == 0) {
        num = self.taskArray.count;
    } else {
        num = self.completedArray.count;
    }
    return num;
}


 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{
   Tasks *taskToMove = [taskArray objectAtIndex:[sourceIndexPath row]];
    if (sourceIndexPath.row > destinationIndexPath.row) {
        [taskArray insertObject:taskToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        [taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row + 1)];
    }
    else if (sourceIndexPath.row < destinationIndexPath.row) {
        [taskArray insertObject:taskToMove atIndex:(destinationIndexPath.row + 1)];
        [taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row)];
    }
}
-(IBAction)addCell:(id)sender{
    Properties2ViewController *pvc = [[Properties2ViewController alloc]init];
    [pvc setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [pvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
}
-(void)properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully:(Tasks *)t{
    if (![[t taskName] isEqual: @""]) {
    [taskArray addObject:t];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Properties2ViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender{
    testTask = [[Tasks alloc]init];
    testTask.taskName = taskName.text;
    testTask.timeInterval = datePicker.countDownDuration;
    testTask.dateCreated = [NSDate date];
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector (properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully:)]){
        [self.delegate properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully:testTask];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Properties2viewcontroller is a modal controller that adds a Task object to the taskArray.

Comment: Try reloading the whole table view as you change more than one row when you move it from one section to another.

Comment: can u provide screen shots for this scenario. so that i can help you which way you want -

Comment: First of all use properties for your arrays (e.g self.taskArray instead taskArray). In this way setters and getters for your properties will be called automatically and you can avoid some possible memory errors. Add lazy instantiation for your arrays (e.g. -(NSMutableArray *)taskArray { if (!_taskArray) { _taskArray = [NSMutableArray array]; } return _taskArray; }) and remove it from viewDidLoad. Set Exceptional breakpoint to see in which method application crashes. Post methods where you add data to all your empty arrays.

Comment: alright i changed both arrays to lazy instantiation :) i never knew about that, thanks for that. i set up an exceptional breakpoint and it looks like there is a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where I declare NSString *detailText = .. and there is another breakpoint at [self.tableview endUpdates]. Could that mean anything?

Comment: something about the objectAtIndex: of 
`NSString *detailText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeInterval]];`

is throwing the program off..

Comment: i think i know your mistake. You try to get value from self.taskArray to set detailText, but your array can be empty at that moment. So you need to write all of your cell configuration code inside conditional statement: if([indexPath section] == 0){
    //config cells in first section
    } else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
    //config cells in second section
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reload rows but what you actually want to do is delete row from section 0 and add it to section 1 or vise versa. So in handlechecking method you must write something like this:

```
-(void)handlechecking:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)t{

CGPoint tapLocation = [t locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = nil;

if (tappedIndexPath.section == 0) {

    NSUInteger newRowIndex = self.sectionTwoArr.count;
    [self.sectionTwoArr addObject:[self.sectionOneArr objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
    [self.sectionOneArr removeObject:[self.sectionOneArr objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
    newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowindex inSection:1];
} else {

    NSUInteger newRowIndex = self.sectionOneArr.count;
    [self.sectionOneArr addObject:[self.sectionTwoArr objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
    [self.sectionTwoArr removeObject:[self.sectionTwoArr objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
    newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowindex inSection:0];
}
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[tappedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

**Edit**

Full implementation of other methods

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.sectionOneArr = [@[@"ololo", @"dsd", @"dsdfsf"] mutableCopy];
    self.sectionTwoArr = [@[@"ototo",@"dd", @"sdfsdfsd"] mutableCopy];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 2;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSInteger num = 0;
    if (section == 0) {
        num = self.sectionOneArr.count;
    } else {
        num = self.sectionTwoArr.count;
    }
    return num;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if([indexPath section] == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.sectionOneArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] uppercaseString];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.jpeg"];
    } else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.sectionTwoArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] uppercaseString];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.jpeg"];
    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlechecking:)];
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    return cell;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString * num = nil;
    if (section == 0) {
        num = @"One";
    } else {
        num = @"Two";
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: that did not work unfortunately. i got a error: I am getting the error * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '* -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: user2533646, i edited my answer and tested it on the test project. it should work

Comment: hmm it semi-worked. sometimes it worked, but when i tapped some of the rows i got: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: also it seems like if i have >1 objects in one section, i can change the section of the object, but if i only have 1, i get an error thats like "index 1 beyond bounds for empty array"

Comment: can you provide more information about your arrays creation? Do you add/remove objects from arrays in other methods than -handlechecking?

Comment: I do add/remove objects in an array which is used to move objects, but thats only in edit mode.

Comment: I added full implementation of my methods, so you can compare them with yours. I have no mentioned errors

Comment: so here is what i did so far: i changed the code so that when the program initializes it has 0 objects in both arrays. heres the weird thing when i implemented your code: when i have an even number of objects (ex: 4) it only lets me press n/2 of them (ex: 4/2 = 2 rows). if i press any more than that i get an error like: [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: if i put in an odd number, like 3, it only lets me press (n-1)/2 checkboxes. ex: ((3-1)/2 = 1). then i get an error like [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: let me compare my methods to yours

Comment: our methods are basically the same, except i initialize my arrays as empty because i have a modal view controller that feeds the objects to the arrays based on user input

Comment: Can you edit your question and post all your code, related to arrays and tableView with all your changes? I can't find error without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct but I would venture a guess that the problem is in your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method. Are you returning the proper count of rows for each section? Should look like this:

```
if([indexPath section] == 0){
   return [taskArray count];
} else {
   return [completeArray count];
}
```

Comment: yea i actually do have that :/